# minishell created in c not working as expected, pipes related

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe

im making an UNIX minishell in c, in my OS signature. I only have to improve the shell itself, we have a premade parser for implement yacc and a scanner for implement lex among other files. 
The file to modify is msh.c, the main executable file.

Well, the problem begins when I try to implement the pipe secuences. This is what I made:

```
int executePipeLine (char*** argvv, int bg, char** filev, int n){
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];

for (i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++){

    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();


    if (pid == 0){ //child

        if (in != STDIN_FILENO){
            dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(in);

        }

        if (fd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO){
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
        }

        execvp(argvv[i][0], argvv[0]);
    }

    else { //parent

        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }


}

if(in != STDIN_FILENO){
    dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(in);
}

pid_t lastpid = fork();
if(lastpid == 0){ //child

execvp(argvv[i][0], argvv[0]);


}

if(lastpid == -1){

    perror("no se pudo crear el hijo\n");
    exit(-1);

}
else { //parent

    /* not bg*/
    if(!bg ) {
    int status;
    while (wait(&status) != lastpid); /* wait the child. */
    }

    else {
    /*bg mode*/
        printf("pid del proceso last: %d\n", lastpid);

    }

    return 0;
}

}//end  executePipeLine
```

This seems to work fine. In the main , where we have an extern function called obtain_order(); that returns the number of commands + 1 and save it to ret. If ret is 1 we continue with the prompt, if is 0 means EOF (Control + D keybinding) to end the shell, and if is >1 execute the commands.

Here you have it:

```
int main(void)
{
    char ***argvv;
    int command_counter;
    int num_commands;
    int args_counter;
    char *filev[3];
    int bg;
    int ret;
    int reset = 0;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);           /* Unbuffered */
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

while (1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", "msh> "); /* Prompt */

    ret = obtain_order(&argvv, filev, &bg);

    printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
    if (ret == 0) break;        /* EOF */
    if (ret == -1) continue;    /* Syntax error */
    num_commands = ret - 1;     /* Line */
    if (num_commands == 0) continue;    /* Empty line */

    if(num_commands > 1){

        executePipeLine(argvv, bg, filev, num_commands);

    }
    else if (num_commands == 1){
        executeCommand(argvv, bg, filev);

    }

} //fin while

return 0;

} //end main
```

All works fine with a simple command. The problem is when I try to execute a pipe line. It show a good result, but i dont know we, after that ret always is 0 in the next iteration, so every time I try to execute a pipe line, it works but close the shell process, and have to execute it again instead of continue with the promt.

You know what is the problem here?

I hope you understand me, my english is not perfec. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent process (i.e. your mini-shell) you are `dup`ing the standard input:

```
...
else { //parent
    close(fd[1]);
    in = fd[0];
}

...

if(in != STDIN_FILENO){
    dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(in);
}
```

When your pipeline terminates, children are dead, pipes are no longer readable => stdin is considered as closed. When you later call `obtain_order` in your main loop, it returns 0 (EOF) and your program exits.

Comment: so you mean I have to delete the dup line? what should i do instead?

Comment: Not sure. If that `dup` is necessary to you, the simplest solution seems to save and restore (with `dup`/`dup2`) the original stdin. You can also execute the whole pipeline in a sub-shell (forked process).

Comment: thanks mate! I finally have executed the pipline in a child process. works perfect